# Unpack dictionary as template tag arguments

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a way to use a dictionary as named arguments in a template tag in Django?

Assuming I have a dictionary like :

```
my_dict = {
    'param1': 'value1',
    'param2': 'value2'
}
```

I know that can do for example :

```
a_function(**my_dict)
```

But can I do something like :

```
{% url 'my_app.viewname' **my_dict %}
```

The url tag is actually what I'm trying to use here, maybe is there an other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django template language is not Python, so no, there's no argument unpacking etc. You can eventually write you own custom `url` tag taking a dict as argument, but that's about it.

Comment: I was about to write the very same thing. An alternative to writing a template tag is to reverse the url in your view instead of the template. There isn't very much code in the question, so it's hard to tell whether that's an option in this case.